# Using React Native Elements, how can I globally style the text color of a <ListItem.Title> component?

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I'm using the [react-native-elements](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/listitem) ui framework with ThemeProvider and trying to globally style the text of a component like this...

```
<ListItem bottomDivider>
  <ListItem.Title>Name</ListItem.Title>
  <ListItem.Input>DoB</ListItem.Input>
</ListItem>
```

I want to style this **<ListItem.Input>** text color red. So I've tried a ton of things similar to the code below, but I can't get anything working. Any ideas?

```
ListItem: {
  inputStyle: {
    color: "red"
  }
}
```

I'd prefer to keep the styling global and not to do it inline, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `ListItemInput`

```
ListItemInput:{
       style:{}
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you! QQ: how did you discover that? Is it anywhere in their docs / is there any way to know that from their docs?

Comment: I checked source code.

Comment: Haha. Not the answer I was hoping for, but I appreciate it. Hopefully they're consistent... <ListItem.Chevron /> is styled via ListItemChevron { style: {} }. So far, it seems like it is.